# Resize my listview item

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a listview of anchor tags. When you click on the anchor tag, it inserts a div with another listview so you can select one of the items. It then removes the sub list view and stores the value in the main listview.

All of this works well except for the fact that the main listview entry stays the same size as it did when it had the other listview in it even though it's empty. I tried getting listview and calling page() on it with no results.

Comment: When I asked my co-worker how I can make it small again, he said, "Just talk to it about your feelings." :)

Comment: Did you try calling it's refresh method (`.listview('refresh')`)?

Comment: Tried refresh. No help.